# Kernel HTC Hero

Tags: cyanogenmod, kernel

I have an HTC Hero GSM with CyanogenMod 7.1.0 (stable). Before i had elelinux mod (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=10956118)

This thing is, after installing CyanogenMod i still have FlyKernel-13.

Should the kernel be changed to the cyanogenmod one? (Screenshot here: http://d.pr/3Sgv )

I have some stability problems with the phone rebooting when using GPS, i'm afraid that's causing it...

Where can i download the correct kernel ?

Comment: Hmm.  How did you install CM?  A normal install shouldn't have kept the kernel, in fact I'm surprised it would even work with that kernel.

Comment: Recovery -> Flashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some phones' partitions have a separate partition for the kernel (often called "boot") that is separate from the one that holds /system.

Unzip the CynanogenMod update.zip - there should be a boot.img inside. If you have fastboot and know how to use it, you can flash boot.img with `./fastboot flash boot /path/to/boot.img`(You will need to be S-OFF for this; sounds like you are.)

Another option is to go back to stock & flash CM again. If you're flashing CM over top of itself you *may* be able to get away without wiping /data (you may still want to wipe /cache)

Answer (score 0):

Did another thing, downloaded Kernel Manager - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teamwin.kernelmanager.free - and downloaded kernel and flash through there. Worked smoothly (ok, not at first, but the second try worked!).

Thanks